# locationInNode returning erroneous results

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a subclass of SKNode called Player which pretty much consists of this: http://hub.ae/blog/2014/03/26/soft-body-physics-jellyusing-spritekit/ converted to swift (With a few changes). I've allowed the user to move the player node with his finger with the following code:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    player.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(touch.locationInNode(world), duration: 1))
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    player.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(touch.locationInNode(world), duration: 1))
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    player.removeAllActions()
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    player.removeAllActions()
}
```

*As a note, the 'world' var you see is just another SKNode. 'player' is a child of this node.

This looks like it should work, however the node moves in very strange directions. This is an example of how it looks:
http://gyazo.com/87b0d09101bbbfd3ac0f2a3cdbf42e4c

How can I fix this? I found that settings the anchor point of the scene to 0.5 fixes this issue, however then the physics body of 'player' node gets messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem but i can not remember if it is how i fixed it. Try changing this:

> world > self

```
player.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(touch.locationInNode(world), duration: 1))
```

To:

```
player.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(touch.locationInNode(self), duration: 1))
```

If i am wrong let me know :)

**EDIT**

set anchor point to (0.5,0.5) and write those 2 methods to center on your node.

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    camera.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x, player.position.y);
    centerOnNode(camera)
}

func centerOnNode(node: SKNode){
    var positionInScene : CGPoint = convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: node.parent)
    world.position = CGPointMake(world.position.x - positionInScene.x, world.position.y - positionInScene.y)
}
```

Comment: This works partially. When I tap above the player node, it moves in the wrong direction, however when I tap below it the node moves correctly.
Here's an example of what's happening: http://gyazo.com/b968913c3ebd482dbc20bf54b869d071
I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you checked coordinates of your touch ? Are they correct ?
Have to tryied 'moveBy' Action?

Comment: After a bit of investigation, I believe that perhaps the problem is my 'center on node' function (Which is called to center the camera on the player). I believe this is changing the correct coordinates (And after testing this without that function running, it seems to be working).  Do you know of a way to fix this? The function is here: http://pastebin.com/QRpQmLab (Pastebinned due to character limit)

Comment: @Aaron check Edit. I wrote how to center on node